# INSERT at Each Step of the Loop

Tags: database, postgresql, loops, plpgsql, sql-insert

Loops in Postgres apparently do a batch insert only at the completion of the loop. I want to do this at each loop step. For example in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION harmonize () RETURNS integer AS $$

  DECLARE

  BEGIN

  FOR i in 1..1000000 LOOP

     INSERT INTO test VALUES (1000, 'some name', 1978002939, 1978002930, 0.0);

  END LOOP;

  RETURN 1;    

  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I would like to see records in the table before all the million steps are over.

Comment: Are you aware that this is highly inefficient? This can be done *much* better using a single `insert` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am aware of that. To test the algorithm that I've developed, it is essential. I am processing about 8M records and I need this functionality to test my implementation. I will worry about optimization later on. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in this kind of function because statements in PostgreSQL run in single transaction. Any changes would be visible to other clients only when statement ends without errors.

You could work this around for example using [`postgres_fdw`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) extension. It can connect to itself and perform insert and commit on every loop step. But it would be extremely inefficient - like 1000 times slower. And it would be hard to configure in secure way.

You could make it much less painful it you perform this inserts in bathes. Like: start transaction, insert 1000 rows, commit, repeat.

Instead I'd implement something like this in external program:

- [`set synchronous_commit=off;`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-async-commit.html)
- use [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) instead of `INSERT`;
- `copy` in bathes of, say, 1000 rows and commit after every batch.